# ¿Cómo mantener chrome abierto por bat?

Tags: batch, .bat

Tengo un Bat el cual quiero que mantenga siempre una pag de google abierta, me refiero a que si cierran chrome, el bat lo detecte y abra nuevamente la pagina que requiero, lo estoy haciendo con un temporalizador, pero no es lo mas conveniente, por que si el usuario esta realizando algún proceso y corre el bat, cierra o deja inconcluso el proceso.

```
@ECHO OFF
:inicio
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
cls
START chrome.exe --kiosk -priting https://www.google.com.mx/
timeout 300 > NUL
cls
goto inicio
```

Comment: Que tal con python podrias usar el módulo webbrowser para abrir la página

Comment: el unico uso que se me ocurre son maliciosos puedes especificar para que quieres saber eso